# Compilation Error: Dummy at (1) cannot have an initializer. What is Dummy Variable?

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I have subroutines defined in a module:

```
MODULE dmotifs

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nsp=4,nrx=8,maxprx=4


TYPE :: PRM
    REAL, PRIVATE :: cref=1e-6,tref=1
    REAL, DIMENSION(nrx,maxprx) :: k
    REAL :: input
END TYPE PRM

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE unreg(y,param,r,s)

        TYPE(PRM), INTENT(IN) :: param
        REAL, DIMENSION(nsp), INTENT(IN) :: y
        INTEGER, DIMENSION(nsp,nrx), INTENT(OUT) :: s=0
        REAL, DIMENSION(nrx,1), INTENT(OUT) :: r=0
        REAL :: mOut, mCtrl, pOut, pCtrl

        mOut=y(ind_mOut)
        mCtrl=y(ind_mCtrl) 
        pOut=y(ind_pOut)
        pCtrl=y(ind_pCtrl)  

        r(1)=param%k(1,1)*mOut
        s(ind_mOut,1)=-1 

        ! and so on ....

END SUBROUTINE unreg
END MODULE dmotifs
```

While I am compiling with gfortran: `gfortran -Wall -c "dmotifs.f90"`, I am getting this error:

```
    SUBROUTINE unreg(y,param,r,s)
                    1
Error: Dummy 'r' at (1) cannot have an initializer
```

I do not understand the nature of this error. I tried keeping and removing `INTENT(OUT)` but it doesn't make any difference.

What is Dummy variable here?

Is this `r(1)=param%k(1,1)*mOut` assignment incorrect?

Comment: Some languages, and texts, use the term *formal argument* for what Fortran uses, and has used for eons, the term *dummy argument*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Unfortunately, the compiler messages do not always follow the Fortran convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just what the compiler tells you: You cannot initialize a dummy variable at the declaration. Your subroutine should read:

```
SUBROUTINE unreg(y,param,r,s)

        TYPE(PRM), INTENT(IN)                    :: param
        REAL, DIMENSION(nsp), INTENT(IN)         :: y
        INTEGER, DIMENSION(nsp,nrx), INTENT(OUT) :: s
        REAL, DIMENSION(nrx,1), INTENT(OUT)      :: r
        REAL :: mOut, mCtrl, pOut, pCtrl

        ! Initialize the output
        s = 0
        r = 0.
        ! and so on ....

END SUBROUTINE unreg
```

The "arguments" `y`, `param`, `r`, and `s` are called *dummy variables* in Fortran to distinguish them from "real" variables like `mOut`.

`r` is a two-dimensional array, so

```
r(1)=param%k(1,1)*mOut
```

is not okay... You probably mean

```
r(1,1)=param%k(1,1)*mOut
```

since the second dimension of `r` has only a length of one.